# Same X-CSRF token passed in all threads of subsequent transactions

Tags: jmeter

I am developing a JMeter script which is as follows:
Test Plan

```
Thread Group 1
     Login
Thread Group 2
Thread Group 3
```

Csrf token is generated in the response of 1 of the login samplers. And as I need this in the request headers of subsequent thread groups so I have set that as a property.
Now when I run this for say 10 threads I observe that as part of login, 10 different csrf tokens are generated but in each of the subsequent thread group only the last csrf token of login is being sent when in fact I expected 10 different csrf tokens to be sent 1 per thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me take a look into my crystal ball and see how you're passing the token. If you use __setProperty() function and provide just a desired property name there - it's absolutely expected because JMeter Properties are **global** for all threads.

The best solution would be moving your "Login" request to the Thread Group where you're going to use the tokens and put it under [Once Only Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Once_Only_Controller) so they would be executed only in 1st iteration.

If your use case is more specific and you desperately need to pass the tokens between Thread Groups just use the the current thread number as a property prefix or postfix.

For example you can use [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) with the following code to store  an user-specific token into an user-specific property:

```
props.put('token_' + (ctx.getThreadNum() + 1), vars.get('variable-holding-your-token-here'))
```

See [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-java-classes) article to learn more about what do these `props`, `vars` and `ctx` objects mean.

And then you can use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) and [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) functions combination to read the token value where required:

```
${__P(token_${__threadNum},)}
```

Demo:

[image]